# How to automatically downcast classes in java?

Tags: java, generics, casting

How would you automatically downcast in Java?

Look at this example:

```java
public class Parent {}

public class Boy extends Parent {}

public class Girl extends Parent {}

Parent father = new Boy();
Parent mother = new Girl();

Boy kid = (Boy)father;
Girl kiddette = (Girl)mother;
```

I know I can downcast manually like in example above, but, how would I do it automatically?

So, what I want is a autocast method, something like this:

```
public ? downcast(? parent) { return ? parent; }
```

which I would use like this:

```java
Boy kid = downcast(father);
Girl kiddette = downcast(mother);
```

So, I do not want to perform any explicit casting in the caller's method. I need `downcast` to hide the casting within itself. Preferrably, I would like to avoid type checks (`instanceof`) within the `downcast` method, so, if downcasting can be generalized, that would be great.

What do I need to place instead of `?`, `?` and `?` to make it work.

I remember that I did this exact same thing 10 or so years ago in Java, and I remember that I was puzzled by the code, but it worked and I did not understand how it works just that it does, but I did not need to do this thing in Java again in the last 10 years, so I forgot what I did. And I remember that I managed to solve it without type checks. So, one line of code that worked for no matter how many child classes parrent class had.

Comment: There is no such thing as "automatic" casting. You are asking the impossible. You should rather question your design if you think you need this feature. For example why not just declare `Boy father = new Boy();`

Comment: <P extends Parent> P downcast(Parent p) {
  return (P) p;
}

Comment: instead of writing `(Boy)father`, you want `downcast(father)` - no great gain, actually one additional method call (and maybe a warning)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can abuse generics to achieve something like this:

```
private static <F, T extends F> T cast(F value) {
    return (T) value;
}
```

Now you can do

```
Parent father = new Boy();
Parent mother = new Girl();
Boy kid = cast(father);
Girl kiddette = cast(mother);
```

This works because the compiler infers the target type from the `kid` variables. It's also dangerous, as evidenced by the generated warning on `(T) value`: "Unchecked cast: 'F' to 'T'". In general, you don't want to do this. All you are doing is tricking the compiler into casts that normally wouldn't be allowed.

Comment: I was about to post something similar. You can even make the cast even more unsafe: `private static <T> T cast(Object value)`. You can then get zero compiler errors when calling `Boy boy = cast("I'm a String, not a Boy!")`. However, there will still be a `ClassCastException`. The compiler is warning about that (the unchecked cast warning), so it's your own fault if you run into it.

Comment: Also, what's the point? Simply avoiding to write the class name again?